# Uncaught TypeError:Button.addEventlistener is not a function

Tags: jquery, html

Whenever I click I want to check if the element has the corresponding class name and alert me. I tried to specify the exact array:

```
const toggleButton = $("#toggle-btn")[0];
```

But I get the same result.

```
<button id="toggle-btn" class="navbar-toggler" type="button">Test</button>
```

```js
const toggleButton = $("#toggle-btn");

function checkButtonClass() {
  if (toggleButton.hasClass("navbar-toggler")){
    alert("I have the Class!");
  } else {
    alert("Nooooo!");
  }
}

toggleButton.addEventListener("click", checkButtonClass);
```

I expect to get the alert message `"I have the class!"`, but instead I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: toggleButton.addEventListener is not a function at scripts.js:12

Comment: jQuery objects do not have that function.

Comment: `addeventListener()` is a method of an Element. `toggleButton` is a jQuery object, so therefore it does not have that method. Use [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on) or [`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click) instead:

Comment: Agreed, if you're using jQuery then you might as well use jQuery's event handling functions

Comment: Thank you very much guys! Is working now. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decide whether to go with JQuery or plain JavaScript DOM elements. If you are using vanilla (plain) JS, you can use the `.addEventListener()` function. However, you have to call it on a standard JS DOM element. For example:

```
const toggleButton = document.getElementById("toggle-btn"); // Get the element
toggleButton.addEventListener("click", checkButtonClass);
```

If you are using Jquery objects, then you have to use the `on` function instead:

```
const toggleButton = $("#toggle-btn"); // get the JQuery element object
toggleButton.on("click", checkButtonClass);
```

Comment: I didn't think about that... I understand now. Is working like a charm now. Thank you!